# Hadoop connection refused

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop in pseudodistributed mode in my mac.Its working. But, every time I start my computer and try to start all the services, I am able to start all the services except the namenode. So, to fix this I format the namenode again and then start all services by calling start-all.sh and everything works. The problem is that all my previous files and directories in my hdfs are deleted because of format. so how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "hadoop.tmp.dir" property in your core-site.xml file and give some proper location as the value. Similarly  add "dfs.name.dir" and "dfs.name.dir" in your hdfs-site.xml file. The default location of these properties is the /tmp directory which gets emptied at each restart.